# membershipTypeValues hook not updating membership price

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, php, hooks

On my civicrm contribution page I have a field that I want to use to calculate the membership price.

Currently Im trying to use the membershipTypeValues hook to edit the price after the contribution page has been submitted

Heres the code

```
add_filter('civicrm_membershipTypeValues', "updatePrice", 10, 2);

function updatePrice(&$form, &$membershipTypeValues) {
    $membershipTypeValues[14]['minimum_fee'] = "40.00";
}
```

Theoretically this should change the membership price to $40 but the price doesn't change on the conformation screen.

The code runs and if I print out the $membershipTypeValues array I can see the minimum fee has changed to $40

Any ideas on how to fix this would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [hook_civicrm_buildAmount](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildAmount/)  or [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook to change the amount on front end contribution/event pages for priceset or line items.

Comment: Thank you, you're right I needed to use buildAmount